# PDO fetch array as row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello I am trying to convert a code from old MSQL to PDO so I can upload and view images from the database, I get the following error code

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Pentaslash\includes\addpost.php on line 60

if i change fetchAll to just fetch it will not identify row[2] the database has the following rows id (PK)  name (imagename)  image(longblob)

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <br/>
        <input type="file" name="image" />
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
            {
                if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE)
                {
                    echo "Please Select an image";
                }
            else
            {
                $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                $name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
                $image= file_get_contents($image);
                $image= base64_encode($image);
                saveimage($name,$image);
            }
            }
        displayimage();
        function saveimage($name,$image)
        {
            try {
            define('SITE_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
            require SITE_ROOT .  '\dbconnect.php';
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
            $sql="INSERT INTO images (name,image) values ('$name','$image')";
                if ($conn->query($sql)) {
                    echo "uplaoded";
                }
                else{
                    echo "failed";
                }

            $conn = null;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            { 
            echo $e->getMessage();
            } 
        }
        function displayimage()
        {
            try {

            require SITE_ROOT . '\dbconnect.php';
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM images");
            $result->execute(); 
            while ($row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<img height="300" width="300" scr="data:image;base64,' .$row[2]. '">';

            }

            $conn = null;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            { 
            echo $e->getMessage();
            } 
        }
        ?>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please `print_r($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` and see what you've missed

Comment: `fetchAll` method returns the whole result in an array, you don't have to go through it with a `while` loop. It's like this: `$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`. Then you can do this: `foreach($rows as $row)`. The `$row` will contain an associative array with your table columns and their values.

Comment: The Array is empty Array ( )  , hmm what did i did wrong here ?

Comment: I dont understand why the array is empty, the database clearly has entry in it, and i even tried the foreach method N.B suggested but nothing happens.

Comment: Empty array means there's nothing in the table. Also, you are **not** using a prepared statement while inserting but you **are** using it when selecting with no parameters passed. That just makes no sense really.. prepared statements are for queries in which you pass some values that you received from user or wherever. Also, the last bad thing you're doing is nullifying your connection - why would you do that? It just makes no sense..

Comment: well is from random advice's I see along the internet, but yeh I am learning bit by bit, right now Ive managed to stop getting an empty Array and can actually get the values in SCR but what ever value i put in t the images are empty, what ever it is. either it is the ID or name or blob it does not display anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so ill put this here for users that have this issue in the future,
1st of all my mistake was that I did not make a foreach loop as mentioned above by the others.
secondly my SCR statement is wrong here is the correct part of the code that will display the base64 images

```
    function displayimage()
    {
    try {
      //  define('SITE_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
        require SITE_ROOT . '\dbconnect.php';
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM images");
        $result->execute(); 
        $rows = $result->fetchAll();    
        foreach($rows as $row):
        echo '<img height="300" width="300"  src="data:image/png;base64, ' . $row[2] . '">';
        endforeach;

        $conn = null;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        { 
        echo $e->getMessage();
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong while fetching. `fetchAll` return an array of the result rows. So all you have to do is to iterate the array:

```
$resultRows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row){
  echo '<img height="300" width="300" scr="' .$row['image']. '">'; // you can also use $row[2]
}
```

An other possibility will be :

```
if ($result->execute(array())) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    echo '<img height="300" width="300" scr="' .$row['image']. '">'; // you can also use $row[2];
  }
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: I still get this error , My array is empty for some strange reason,I dont uderstand what is happening

Comment: Can you check in a mysql console like the one you get from phpMyAdmin or the one that you get from terminal connection `mysql -h $HOST -u $USER -p$PASSWORD`, if the select query return results?

Comment: so right now i tried doing a foreach thingy and it loads whatever i want in $row['image'] but it does not display an image. I dont know why it does that. but i can get the name , id or the image blob in scr, any idea what could be the cause of this ?

Comment: the problem with not showing the images was in my scr code. here is the correct one echo `'<img height="300" width="300"  src="data:image/png;base64, ' . $row[2] . '">';`

Answer (score 2):

Using fetchAll() and foreach loop, you can try this:

```
    $rows = $result->fetchAll();    
    foreach($rows as $row):
     echo '<img height="300" width="300" scr="data:image;base64,' .$row['image']. '">';
    endforeach;
```

if you still want to use the while loop, it should be:

```
 while($rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      echo '<img height="300" width="300" scr="data:image;base64,' .$row['image']. '">';
}
```